# How do i run the dist upgrade on a forcepae install?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, pae, non-pae

I think the main issue based on this line in the error message from the package manager.

> This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.

How do I run the dist upgrade on a forcepae install?

**Extra info about my installation:**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename: vivid

$ uname -a
Linux justin-Inspiron-8600 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:01 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-15-generic root=UUID=08ba681b-f340-4554-a283-fda4a60b2f59 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

$ grep -m3 -e '^model name' -e '^flags' -e '^address size' /proc/cpuinfo
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 1.60GHz
flags   : fpu vme de pse tsc msr mce cx8 sep mtrr pge mca cmov clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss tm pbe bts est tm2
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
```

**Error message follows**

```
(synaptic:31640): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion
pid > 0' failed
/usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-default/gtk-2.0/apps/thunar.rc:55: error:
invalid string constant "thunar-statusbar", expected valid string
constant /usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-default/gtk-2.0/apps/thunar.rc:55:
error: invalid string constant "thunar-statusbar", expected valid
string constant (Reading database ... 144711 files and directories
currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
.../linux-image-3.19.0-51-generic_3.19.0-51.58_i386.deb ...
/usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-default/gtk-2.0/apps/thunar.rc:55: error:
invalid string constant "thunar-statusbar", expected valid string
constant /usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-default/gtk-2.0/apps/thunar.rc:55:
error: invalid string constant "thunar-statusbar", expected valid
string constant This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU. dpkg:
error processing archive
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-51-generic_3.19.0-51.58_i386.deb
(--unpack):  subprocess new pre-installation script returned error
exit status 1 Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d . run-parts: executing
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-51-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-51-generic run-parts: executing
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-51-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-51-generic Preparing to unpack
.../gvfs-backends_1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb ... Unpacking
gvfs-backends (1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1) over (1.24.1-1ubuntu1) ... Preparing
to unpack .../gvfs-fuse_1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb ... Unpacking
gvfs-fuse (1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1) over (1.24.1-1ubuntu1) ... Preparing to
unpack .../gvfs_1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb ... Unpacking gvfs:i386
(1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1) over (1.24.1-1ubuntu1) ... Preparing to unpack
.../gvfs-daemons_1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb ... Unpacking gvfs-daemons
(1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1) over (1.24.1-1ubuntu1) ... Preparing to unpack
.../gvfs-libs_1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb ... Unpacking gvfs-libs:i386
(1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1) over (1.24.1-1ubuntu1) ... Preparing to unpack
.../gvfs-common_1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb ... Unpacking gvfs-common
(1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1) over (1.24.1-1ubuntu1) ... Preparing to unpack
.../libnautilus-extension1a_1%3a3.14.2-0ubuntu9.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnautilus-extension1a (1:3.14.2-0ubuntu9.1) over
(1:3.14.2-0ubuntu9) ... Preparing to unpack
.../nautilus-data_1%3a3.14.2-0ubuntu9.1_all.deb ... Unpacking
nautilus-data (1:3.14.2-0ubuntu9.1) over (1:3.14.2-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-3ubuntu1) ... Processing
triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.44.1-1ubuntu1) ... Processing
triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ... Processing triggers for
shared-mime-info (1.3-1) ... Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-51-generic_3.19.0-51.58_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) A package
failed to install.  Trying to recover: Setting up nautilus-data
(1:3.14.2-0ubuntu9.1) ... Setting up gvfs-common (1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1)
... dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
linux-image-extra-3.19.0-51-generic: 
linux-image-extra-3.19.0-51-generic depends on
linux-image-3.19.0-51-generic; however:   Package
linux-image-3.19.0-51-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-51-generic
(--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up
gvfs-libs:i386 (1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1) ... Setting up
libnautilus-extension1a (1:3.14.2-0ubuntu9.1) ... dpkg: dependency
problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic: 
linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.19.0-51-generic; however:
Package linux-image-3.19.0-51-generic is not installed. 
linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.19.0-51-generic;
however:   Package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-51-generic is not
configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up gvfs-daemons
(1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1) ... Setting up gvfs:i386 (1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic: 
linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.19.0.51.50);
however:   Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up gvfs-backends
(1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1) ... Setting up gvfs-fuse (1.24.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ... Errors were
encountered while processing:  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-51-generic 
linux-image-generic  linux-generic
```

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Well would yee look at that! Will do cheers.

Comment: OK thanks. This did the trick. Just add the pae flag an I am away.
Cheers
```cat /proc/cpuinfo | sed 's/flags\t*:/& pae/' > /tmp/cpuinfo_pae
sudo mount -o bind /tmp/cpuinfo_pae /proc/cpuinfo
sudo mount -o remount,ro,bind /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: Damn, How do i do <pre> in these comments?

Comment: Comments don't support code listings (see the [comment editing help](/editing-help#comment-formatting)). If you want to add information to your question [edit] it. If you want to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer), please do so. In both cases, use [code listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar).

Answer (score 2):

> ### Upgrading
>
> #### Install a PAE kernel (to verify your system is PAE capable)
>
> First, run
>
> ```sh
> apt-get install linux-image-generic-pae
> ```
>
> Reboot and then run
>
> ```sh
> uname -a
> ```
>
> This should output a line where the version number (eg. 3.11.0-17) ends with "-generic" and is 3.11.x or above.
>
> #### Add the PAE flag to processor information
>
> To add the PAE flag to the processor information stored in `/proc/cpuinfo`, run the following:
>
> ```sh
> cat /proc/cpuinfo | sed 's/flags\t*:/& pae/' > /tmp/cpuinfo_pae
> sudo mount -o bind /tmp/cpuinfo_pae /proc/cpuinfo
> sudo mount -o remount,ro,bind /proc/cpuinfo
> ```
>
> After you have ran those commands, run
>
> ```sh
> grep flags /proc/cpuinfo
> ```
>
> If the flag was correctly added, the command returns a line that starts with `flags :` and contains the flag `pae`.

<sup>Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE/PentiumM#Upgrading</sup>

Comment: First bit did not work for me but adding the flag did